# How should an onChange event be annotated in an exported React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a React Component with an `onChange` handler:

```
// @flow
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class MyList extends Component {
  handleChange = (event) => {
    // Do something with event.target.value
    // which will be the value typed in the input field.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}> />
    );
  }
}
```

and Flow complains about this because it is an exported class:

`` Parameter `event` missing annotation ``

How can I annotate the `event` parameter in the handleChange function? As far as I know, this event is generated at the JavaScript level and doesn't have any Flow typing.

Alternatively, can Flow be configured to not display these "missing annotation" errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the typings here https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js

```
handleChange = (event: Event) => {
  if (event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Initially I tried `Event` and it didn't work but after updating to the latest version of flow (via brew) and adding `esproposal.class_instance_fields=enable` under `[options]` in my `.flowconfig` file, I don't get any further errors or warnings about it. However, now I'm getting an error message that the property `value` cannot be found. Any idea how to fix that? `event.target` returns the `input` tag as a JS object.

Comment: @RyanH. Here's a fully working example with flow 0.34 https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMY4A0oA3qAMKwawB2hzeAvqJFo6AORYS5fgG5EiQgA9MuUABNCkYgFdoeUtGIBnbaACyATwAyybXmk428vQyat2NRKFDPQAC2LN50QnU-MAOaEoAC8oAAUhABubDgAXKAAorHsAJRhAHxOLgCQyJCRMXEAdDjEWMF4yMzmXqSEsIUAEgAq+sYAkszoKjhJvqhxGdRuLi6kLNqwviVwgVGpOGUVVSXRxNAqhGnieRxuB+OuHEA

Answer (score 5):

I found another solution, using synthetic events: something like the following

```js
onChange (event: SyntheticInputEvent<EventTarget>): void {
  this.setState({ text: event.target.value })
}
```

Comment: You can be even more specific with `SyntheticInputEvent<HTMLInputElement>`